# MySQL8 connection with php7.3 and Symfony 5 does not work

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a connection problem with a mysql8 database, php7.3 and Symfony 5. The user and the password are correct !

The connection to MySQL8 database must be done from an SSH tunnel

The SSH tunnel is working :

```
ssh -p [remote_machine_port] -N -L [mysql_tunnel_port]: 127.0.0.1: 3306 -i / [directory] / private_key [username] @ [remote_machine_ip]
```

MySQL access configuration:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'databasename'.* TO '[user]'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Doctrine configuration :

```
DATABASE_URL='mysql://[user]:[password]@127.0.0.1:[port_tunnel_mysql]/[databasename]'

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE [HY000] [1130] Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I have the same problem with heidiSQL and on the VM

I tried with the Ip of the VM instead of 127.0.0.1

```
ssh -p [port_machine_distant] -N -L [port_tunnel_mysql]:[ip_machine_vm]:3306 -i /[directory]/private_key [username]@[ip_machine_distant]
```

Doctrine configuration

```
DATABASE_URL='mysql://[user]:[password]@[ip_machine_vm]:[port_tunnel_mysql]/[databasename]'

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

However, this setting works with heidiSQL but not with the Symfony application !

Did I forget a setting on the VM or Mysql ?

Comment: If you have the same problem using other tools, I would assume that the basic configuration is faulty and this is not in any way related to PHP or Symfony

Comment: Yes for the 127.0.0.1 settings, but when i use ip of the vm, i can connect with heidsql but not Symfony application

Comment: Are you able to connect via the command-line, without Symfony or PHP?

Comment: Yes the command-line works... mysql -u[user] -p

Comment: But command-line mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u[user] -p returns an error : Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

127.0.0.1 connection issue :
We have created the '[user]'@'127.0.0.1' rights.
In MySQL, 127.0.0.1 uses the network and localhost uses the socket.

The message "The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]" was caused because the setting 'default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password' was created after the creation of the rights.
We regenerated the rights, and now everything is working fine.